# Error when customising EC2 instance php.ini file on AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk on AWS and I'm trying to override some settings from the php.ini file. I've made the directory /.ebextensions with project.config within it:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
  mode: "000644"
  owner: ec2-user
  group: ec2-user
  content: |
    date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
    error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
    display_errors = Off
```

When I redeploy the application, EBS throws the following error:

```
The configuration file __MACOSX/gf/.ebextensions/._project.config in application version gf3 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: unacceptable character '' (0x0) special characters are not allowed in "<reader>", position 0, JSON exception: Unexpected character () at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
```

What have I done wrong?

UPDATE:

__MACOSX/ removed from archive now throwing error:

```
The configuration file gf/.ebextensions/project.config in application version gf4 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: while scanning for the next token found character '\t' that cannot start any token in "<reader>", line 7, column 1: date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin" ^ , JSON exception: Unexpected character (f) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
```

There seems to be something wrong with the file, but I can't spot what.

EDIT: I needed to remove a couple of tabs from the file and replace with spaces. This fixed it along with the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using a Macintosh, and you let [the hidden `__MACOSX` directories](https://superuser.com/q/104500/144961) get into your deployment. These files are generated when you zip up a directory to hold the OS X specific resource forks, which are useless on any other operating system.

If you're going to use `zip` to package your app for deployment, you need to remove these Better to use `git`, Capistrano, or something actually suited to deploying software.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried removing it, but there seems to be something else wrong with the file. I've just started using Git and not familiar with how I can use it with elastic beanstalk. Do you know of a good tutorial?